# FileOutputStream for a shared printer when there is no network

Tags: java, networking, printing, network-printers

I'm working with Java under Windows XP. In order to print in old Epson printers I use a `FileOutputStream`. For example:

```
ostream = new FileOutputStream(printer);
pstream = new PrintStream(ostream);

//reset default settings
pstream.print(ESC);
pstream.print(AT);
```

To initialize the `FileOutputStream` I use the network name of the printer, for example `"\\Server\Printer"`. This works fine if the computer is connected to a network, but if there is no network available I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` with the message "The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help". **`Server` is the name of the computer where I'm running the app. Anyway, if I use `"\\localhost\Printer"` I get the same error.**

I tried the Windows file explorer to see if I get this error there, in case this is a Windows thing. If I try to enter some local shared folder (`\\Server\Folder`) without being connected to a network I get the same error. However, **if I write `\\Server\Printer` the file explorer opens the printer.**

So, **how can I initialize the `FileOutputStream` when there is no network available?**

**EDIT:** I have several printers connected to the server through LPT1 and USB ports. The same program runs in other computers and that is why I use the shared name of the printers. However, if someone unplug the Server from the network, I want my program to continue working normally on the Server.

I have this running for years, but some days ago I wanted to change one router and for that I disconnected the Server. Then, I got this error, but as the printers are connected to the Server the program should work on the Server no matter the network availability.

Comment: I don't suppose it's a really old printer on a parallel port?  Then you could write to LPT1.

Comment: Your question makes zero sense. If the printer isn't accessible you *should* get an exception. What's your issue with that?

Comment: @EJP My printer is accessible, it is in the same computer and, as I said in the post, I can access to it through the Windows file explorer using its shared name

Comment: @GuidoSimone I have several printers, one on the LPT1 but the others through USB

Comment: You are using a network name for the printer, which doesn't work if there is no network.

Comment: @EJP The question is: how can I initialize the FileOutputStream when there is no network available?. I guess the only option would be to use the port of the printer when the printer is local